# Давайте уберём ограничение на предложение синонимов меток

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

При попытке добавлять синонимы меток встречаюсь часто с таким сообщением "Для создания синонима метки необходимо набрать по ней 5 баллов рейтинга.".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае и во многих других вижу его вредным, так как мог бы предлагать синонимы по тем меткам, по которым у меня нет ни вопросов, ни ответов.

В итоге либо придётся писать модераторам в чате, либо создавать вопрос на мете. Это мне кажется излишним для каждого такого действия.

Comment: Связанный, очень похожий вопрос: [Проблема синонимизации меток](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1543/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: всегда можно пнуть модераторов.

Comment: @Grundy А я же тут предлагаю, чтобы можно было бы создавать именно "предложение" для синонимов. А не единолично решать. Я так полагаю, они так смогут увидеть и затем принять предложение или отклонить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov метка [tag:язык] совсем не похожа на [tag:любой-язык]

Comment: @PashaPash Согласен, метка [tag:язык] больше подходит для [tag:локализация]. Я хотел метку [tag:языки] предложить для [tag:любой-язык]. Может это неверно, но по смыслу вопросов подходит.

Comment: @PashaPash А вообще метка [tag:язык] нужна?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov и для локализации не подходит. Это мета-метка, она просто не нужна.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да я уже это понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ограничение на создание синонимов может быть снято исключительно в целях чистки крайне нишевых меток, по которым задано всего несколько вопросов, на некоторое не продолжительное время. Для этого необходимо поднять соответствующие обсуждение на Мете.

В общем случае, убирать требования нельзя, так как необходимо понимать о чем идет речь, предлагая синоним. Механизм синонимизации можно рассматривать как переименование метки. Метки задают ветвление. Без понимания предметной области, может наступить хаос.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда лучше буду просить для конкретных меток сделать синонимы у модераторов.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Так поступают многие. Самое простое – написать об этом в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), и, в случае несогласия, кто–либо из присутствующих всегда может поделиться альтернативным взглядом.